# Understanding how WebJobs run

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am struggling to answer this question for myself so can anyone answer it for me. How, exactly, do webjobs get run? By this I mean does the Azure framework manage access to the WebJob and are multiple instances run in separate processes?

I am under the impression that I get 12 or 16 parrallel instances by default. Is this correct? So if three messages are placed on a queue, that my webjob is triggered by, they will all run in parrallel.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, when you scale out multiple instances, the webjobs will run on the instances in parallel in separate processes. But there are prerequisites of it,

1. The webjob should be **continous** and not Manual/Scheduled.
2. For this to happen correctly, you need to be running in Standard mode, and have the **Always On** setting enabled.

**Note**: If you use TimerTrigger in your webjob, it will not scale out. Refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger).

> Behind the scenes, **TimerTrigger uses the Singleton feature of the WebJobs SDK to ensure that only a single instance of your triggered function is running at any given time**. When the JobHost starts up, for each of your TimerTrigger functions a blob lease (the Singleton Lock) is taken. This distrubuted lock ensures that only a single instance of your scheduled function is running at any time.

For more details about the issue, here are two similar posts for you to refer, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461772/multiple-azure-webjob-instances-on-one-queue) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710755/will-an-azure-web-job-run-on-multiple-instances).

Comment: Interesting about the TimerTrigger I didn't realise that but for continuous jobs I am referring to how it runs on an instance. I have noticed that if I have more than one message on a queue they appear to be processed in parrallell. How is this managed/administered.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth As mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461772/multiple-azure-webjob-instances-on-one-queue) in my reply, each job instance will pick a different message from the queue via  [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki).

Comment: BatchSize is what I wanted to know about. config.Queues.BatchSize controls the number of items that will be processed in parrellel. So an instance can process more than one item. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues#-parallel-execution

Comment: @onesixtyfourth Yes, in short the SDK will manage it. Glad your issue has been solved.